# Kafka Connect - No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I run my sink connector, also a new kafka topic is created as soon as the connector work. Until this point everything works fine. But, as soon as I enter a new value into kafka producer, it turns out the error `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres`.

My config files are as below:

connect-standalone.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=C:/Users/me/Desktop/connectors/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
```

connect-sink-postgres.properties (my sink file):

```
name=psql-sink-connector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
topics=test-topic
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
connection.user=postgres
connection.password=postgres
table.name.format=test
pk.fields=id
insert.mode=insert
tasks.max=1
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
auto.create=true
```

consumer.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
```

The data in test-topic:

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type": "string","optional":true,"field":"msg"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"importance"}],"optional":false,"name":"test"},"payload":{"id":1,"msg":"test msg","importance":"test imp"}}
```

Also, my DB name is `kafkatest` and the name of the only table in the database is `test`. It has `id (integer primary key)`, `msg (varchar)`, `importance (varchar)` as fields.

Why is that error occuring?

Comment: Well, where did you put the Postgres JDBC driver jar?

Comment: I am currently using Windows 10, that's why I have put JDBC driver jar in a set of folders, in my desktop (just for testing) and provided absolute path to the file called connect-standalone.properties .

Comment: The driver itself isn't a Connect "plugin" class, however, so you will need to add that JAR to the CLASSPATH environment variable before running connect-standalone

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for the quick reply. I could solve the error by changing my operating system.

Comment: Have you tried using official distro from confluent? You can run it in docker and install all plugins with CLI without headache of compatibility. For example, `confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.4.1`

Comment: @themoah That doesn't download the driver, only the connector

Comment: @OneCricketeer are you sure about that? Based on connector info it connect to any DB that support jdbc-based connection. (Also we use it for both source and sink exactly this way). 
[https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc)

Also, based on their [pom](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/pom.xml#L60) they already bundle with driver to Postgres, oracle and other DB engines.

Comment: @themoah The pom doesn't package the JDBC drivers. Primarily for licensing restrictions. That's true for at least mysql and oracle. I'm not sure about Postgres.

Comment: @OneCricketeer the jdbc drivers are listed in the pom on lines 59-62. Their scope is `runtime`

Comment: @themoah As mentioned, `runtime` scope does not include them in the Connector ZIP/JAR output. They need to be downloaded separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though having an absolute path for drivers, kafka connect raised error in Windows. By writing the `plugin.path` properly and placing the drivers to the path, same kafka connect files that didn't work in Windows worked well in Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It works fine in Windows if configured correctly. For instance, Windows paths need double backslash, but your question has forward slashes

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know that. Thank you for the information, that will surely help the ones who work on Windows OS.